# How to generate a product license key which includes decodable product information

Tags: java, security, encryption

I want to issue a product security key which can encode details of the licensing restrictions. For example, a key could contain the maximum number of licensed users, and/or start/end dates to control license expiry.

I know that a simple way of creating a key is to use an MD5 hash - simply concatenate the details and apply the MD5 hash algorithm. But that is a one way process i.e. you cannot decode the key to see the initial parameters.

What I want to do is issue a key which can be decoded at the user site, and gives them all the licensing parameters.

So the user would get something like this:

1234-5678-9012-3456

which is created using a string composed of the following parameters, concatenated, then hashed

Max users: **50**

Start date: **17/01/17**

End date: **17/01/18**

In the past I've installed software products which come with a license key , and the key somehow has all the information such as expiry date built in. How is this done? Does the software contact a central server to determine the expiry date by consulting a database?
But I'm sure these license keys worked when the application was offline. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Does the software contact a central server to determine the expiry date by consulting a database? if you want it to be secured, them yes. As for offline behavior - you can implement whatever you want, you can allow the users to run the product for free when offline, or, create a retry mechanism which outputs an error message that explains to the user they have to be online in order to run your app. Up to you!

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, forgot to mention that some of our site installations do not have Internet connectivity.

Comment: And now that you're mentioning it, what do you expect us to say? it's way less secure, but if that's your limitation - accommodate it!

Comment: Ok, I can simply transmit the plain licensing details along with the key. That's not a problem.

Comment: how can you "transmit" if there is no connection ?

Comment: The license key is transmitted via email. But there is no Internet connectivity for the product itself.

Comment: Maybe something similar to a JWT token?  Specify your parameters in a JSON object, sign it with your private key, then encode the whole thing to base64.  It will be pretty long but will work.

Comment: @LukePark and how does he make sure the same license-key is not used in different machines ?

Comment: Using the same license key on different machines is not an issue.

Comment: @alfasin Well that is kind of the issue for all of the given solutions.

Comment: @LukePark not if you're forcing the user to be online during registration ;)

Comment: @alfasin Except the OP isn't forcing that... So... That isn't relevant?

Comment: @LukePark it's relevant to understand the pros and cons of your requirements as well as limitations.

Comment: @alfasin Didn't the OP literally just say that the key being used on different machines is not a problem?

Comment: @LukePark right, but when I started commenting it was before that ;)

Comment: @alfasin Well, you win then! -.-

Comment: @LukePark did we compete ? :))) sorry if I came up argumentative, that wasn't the intention. All the best!

Comment: @alfasin Just seemed unnecessary, no worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically what you can do is: create a datastructure holding your information, encode that as bytes, pipe through a compression function if too large.

create a keypair for your favourite signing algo like RSA

sign the data structure / the compressed bytes

truncate the signature to a fitting size like the last X hex digits

ship the public key with your product

the longer the signature part, the harder to make a working keygen

it's more likely someone will replace you key or the checking logic in your binary, but yes... that's how you could do this...

Comment: A truncated (by more than a few bytes) RSA signature cannot be verified, which makes it useless here. A truncated hash or keyed-hash (like HMAC) _can_ be verified (at a weaker level) but can easily be forged. I don't see why you want a short signature here but see http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/how-do-i-create-a-short-signature-e-g-less-than-100-bytes and/or http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84040/how-can-i-generate-short-signatures

Comment: right... that happens when i do too many things at the same time ...the idea was to reduce the length of the whole thing, but yes... you need the untruncated sig to verify

Answer (score 1):

I have developed an open source solution for that.

I'd be happy if someone would give it a try.
https://github.com/mitch-haraldsson/greenLicense

It is exactly what you are looking for, since I had the same requirements for my software.

Keep in mind that no software is uncrackable. An attacker determined enough will crack every - offline - license.

I am using a pretty standard approach.
A key pair (public is shipped with the software) to encrypt a unique symmetric key in the license which encrypts your payload of any size.

A signature ensures that the file has not been tempered with.

In addition you can bind the license to certain system attributes like

- mac address
- ip address
- host name
- os name

Of course, as stated before, determined attackers will get through almost anything. The goal is not to make it too easy to illegally redistribute your software.

Comment: Hi, Many Thanks for this. This is really helpful. One small point - Line # 48 of GreenLicenseReaderBase should be '(lines.length > 0)' instead of '(lines.length > 1), right? It was not reading my sole feature, and when I changed it, it worked.

Comment: @VimalBhatt, Thank you for pointing that out. I will check this this week and commit the changes :)